# Joining nhibertnate query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am trying to join the results of two nhibernate queries. The problem I am facing here is that it first gets all the rows for both the queries and then performs the where, which enormously slows it down. This is happening because I am doing a List(). But without it the join cannot be made.

```
var results=  from u in session.QueryOver<User>().List()
                        join ur in session.QueryOver<UserRights>().List()
                            on u.Id equals ur.User.Id
                        where u.Deleted == false && (ur.Role.Id == 10 || ur.Role.Id == 20)
```

How do I build the statement so that the query doesn't get all the users and user rights before the join and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `linq` with `nhibernate` your have to use the `session.Query<T>` instead `session.QueryOver<T>`. Try this:

```
// prepare the query
var query = from u in session.Query<User>()
            join ur in session.Query<UserRights>() on u.Id equals ur.User.Id
            where u.Deleted == false && (ur.Role.Id == 10 || ur.Role.Id == 20)
            select u;

// execute query and get list
var results = query.ToList();
```

Also, avoid to use `.ToList()` to create your query beacuse it will load all entities in memory (executing a complete query) and execute a Linq To Object in memory. Using like this, you will hit a query database where you need.